# Access Azure Storage download URL link in Web Application

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service, azure-storage

I am referring to below design figure 2:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/architecture/web-apps/app-service/architectures/baseline-zone-redundant
In this design Web Applications and Web API (hosted on App Services) can all be private. Also, the Storage service be accessed privately by App Services. I am following the same design for my application as well.

But my additional need is to show a URL in my web application which should be Storage URL(Blob Storage) so the user can directly download documents instead of routes through Web Application Page--> Web Application App Service--> REST API App Service--> Storage Container.

Is the SAS token the solution? Private links on Storage can stay and users can still click links on Web Applications (URL of storage directly).

Answer (score 0):

A SAS token would work, although it does mean your storage account won't have a firewall to make it work. You will also be less in control of the connections made to your storage (e.g. a user downloading a file 100x). You can still use a private endpoint to limit your API's outgoing connections, but otherwise the private endpoint won't be effective.

In case you setup your environment using the Azure Portal you should make sure you enable the firewall after creating the private link endpoint as operations through the portal tend to automatically disable public network access.

To further elaborate on the SAS token and give an example of a basic setup. The API could have the credentials (e.g. an access key of the storage account) that'll allow it to generate a SAS token (with limitations). A request to the API could then create a SAS token for a specific document and return its url to consume in your web page and link your user directly to the file.